# Java, JDBC: StreamCorruptedException while trying to retrieve an object from database

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a problem with retrieving properly a specific object of my own class "BallotPaper" from a database. It saves properly but at the time of creating an ObjectInputStream, an  exception is thrown.

Of course I have read many of similar questions and answers here but still cannot deal with it.

In the database I have a table with a column of bytea type (it is postgreSQL) where I save my object.

Here are several lines of code:

```
//Saving the object 'paper' of the class 'BallotPaper'
    PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(byos);
    oos.writeObject(paper);
    byte[] bytePaper = byos.toByteArray();
    st.setBytes(1, bytePaper);
    st.executeUpdate();

    byos.close();
    oos.close();
    st.close(); 

//Trying to retrieve the object:
    String query2 = "SELECT paper FROM voters WHERE id="+_id+";";
    Statement s = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    ResultSet r = s.executeQuery(query2);
    r.first();
    bytePaper = r.getBytes(1);
    ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytePaper);
    ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b); // *
    BallotPaper ba = (BallotPaper)o.readObject();
```

The Exception is thrown at the line before last, marked with  * .

It looks like that:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: BB656430
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at slave.VotersDB.saveFilledPaper(VotersDB.java:162)
at slave.ClientThread.prepareResponse(ClientThread.java:50)
at slave.ClientThread.run(ClientThread.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thank you for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `flush()`:

```
oos.writeObject(paper);
oos.flush();
byte[] bytePaper = byos.toByteArray();
```

The `ObjectOutputStream` is allowed to buffer its output. You could alternatively call `close()` rather than `flush()`, which will at least make it clear that you shouldn't use the streams again.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with flush().
After saving, I am closing all the streams.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve the problem. It turned out to be unsuited for saving binary data to use setBytes() method. Instead one should use setBinaryStream().

With the first method, the bytes of the serialized object were totally different from those original. Anybody knows why ?

Here is the proper code:

```
PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(query);    

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(paper); 
byte[] bytePaper = baos.toByteArray();

PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream();
PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream(pis);
pos.write(bytePaper);   
pos.flush();

st.setBinaryStream(1, pis,bytePaper.length);
```

The way of retrieving does not change.

Comment: What is the type of the column that you're inserting into? Is it a `BINARY`, `VARBINARY`, `RAW`, or `BLOB`? Or is it a character type?